# Edit a web page with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-chrome

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39283333/python-to-view-and-manipulate-web-page?noredirect=1#comment65902596_39283333) about how to edit a web page with Python before using selenium, but since that didn't get anywhere (I want to be able to do it in a browser that still has all of the saved cookies, passwords, bookmarks, etc) I want to broaden the scope.  Using any modules you know of, how can I open a website in my browser, and edit an element using a Python script?

For instance I'd like my script to do something like this...

```
open google.com
find the element that corresponds to the google logo
hide the element
```

If it helps, I'm on a Macbook, using Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

You can still do that via `selenium`, locate the element and edit the `style` via "execute script":

```
elm = driver.find_element_by_id("myid")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'none';", elm)
```

Comment: Right, but when I use selenium I lose all of those bookmarks, passwords, and cookies that I mentioned in the post

Answer (score 0):

to open google we can use :

```
    import webbrowser
    webbrowser.chrome("url to open")
```

**I dont know for others.**